# Python 3: receive user input including newline characters

Tags: python, input, python-3.x

I'm trying to read in the following text from the command-line in Python 3 (copied verbatim, newlines and all):

```
lcbeika
rraobmlo
grmfina
ontccep
emrlin
tseiboo
edosrgd
mkoeys
eissaml
knaiefr
```

Using `input`, I can only read in the first word as once it reads the first newline it stops reading.

Is there a way I could read in them all without iteratively calling `input`?

Answer (score 11):

You can `import sys` and use the methods on `sys.stdin` for example:

```
text = sys.stdin.read()
```

or:

```
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

or:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    # Do something with line.
```

Answer (score -2):

if you are passing the text into your script as a file , you can use `readlines()`

eg

```
data=open("file").readlines()
```

or you can use `fileinput`

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    print line
```

Comment: I'm reading it from the command-line, not passing the text as a file.