# Accept newline character in python

Tags: python

I want to accept new line input in python.

I am trying

```
s = input('''Enter the paragraph :''')
```

But when i input paragraph.. on the very first ENTER it stops taking further input lines.

So how to accept newline character as input in Python

and then how to print the paragraph as it is on the screen.?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542171/python-3-receive-user-input-including-newline-characters

Comment: error with 'sys' .. says "name 'sys' is not defined"

Comment: did you remember to `import sys`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This answer assumes that you are using Python 3. If you are using Python 2.x, use the one provided by Anthon.

Do something like this:

```
text = ''
while True: # change this condition.
    text += input('''Enter the paragraph :''')+'\n' #UPDATED. Appended a \n character.
```

For example, you want to end the input sequence by an extra newline character, then the code would be:

```
text = ''
while True:
    dummy = input('''Enter the paragraph :''')+'\n'
    if dummy=='\n':
        break
    text += dummy
```

Comment: what condition should i impose in while..?

Comment: It depends how do you want to end the input. I am going to update the answer.

Comment: Have a boolean that becomes false when you enter type a certain terminating string.

Comment: I assume that OP uses Python 3. I've updated my answer to show my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

from [Python 3: receive user input including newline characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542171/python-3-receive-user-input-including-newline-characters)

i have done the below :

```
import sys


text = sys.stdin.read()
print(text)
```

and this make my task.

Comment: When the user enters a multi-line input, how can they stop entering new characters to return control to the program?