# Python 3.5 changing line when there is an Enter in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input, line

When I am entering a string input that contains line breaks, Python thinks that I have pressed Enter and continues to the next commands.

How can I put `\n` when Enter is pressed, to send the rest to an extra line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3: receive user input including newline characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542171/python-3-receive-user-input-including-newline-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, if you have a paragraph to execute without a break, 
Use triple quotes .
Here's is an example :

```
para_str = """this is a long string that is made up of
several lines and non-printable characters such as
TAB ( \t ) and they will show up that way when displayed.
NEWLINEs within the string, whether explicitly given like
this within the brackets [ \n ], or just a NEWLINE within
the variable assignment will also show up.
"""
print (para_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue processing of the same command to the next line, add a backslash ('\') before a '\n'